# Scala: Using right type class instance for reflected/runtime instance

Tags: scala, reflection, typeclass

I have a simple trait

```
trait BusinessObject {}
```

and a simple type-class

```
trait Printer[T<:BusinessObject] { def print(instance:T): Unit }
```

In my code base I have a few hundred implementations of `BusinessObject`. Some are direct implementers, some implement sub-traits of `BusinessObject`, and some add various mixin traits using `with`. I have around 10 different special implementations of `Printer` (defined on the various sub-traits and mixins), and a low-priority generic fallback instance for any other `BusinessObject` and it works a charm.

I need to document all the implementations of `BusinessObject` in the code base, so I have used Scala's reflection mechanism to enumerate these, and now want to apply a Printer on each. The method signature of the reflection mechanism is

```
def enumerateBOs: Traversable[BusinessObject]
```

It returns one instance of each `BusinessObject` implementation. My problem is that at runtime there seems to be no way to get the right (specific) Printer for each object in this traversable.

I have tried summoning using `.type` like this:

```
enumerateBOs.head match { case bo => Printer[bo.type].print(bo) }
```

but I get the generic fallback `Printer` for every element.

Is there some way to do what I want to do? Or, if implicits really only are available at compile time, some way to list all implementers of `BusinessObject` at compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicits (as all generics in Scala) are really a compile-time mechanism and it's not possible to locate all implementations of a non-sealed trait at compile time.

---

That being said, it's not hard to run Scala compiler at runtime.

Get your dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.12.3",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.12.3"
)
```

You only need a `ToolBox` object to get everything done - it parses a string, then compiles parsed tree to a function `() => Any`, which, when called, gives the result of an expression. The code does not have an access to surrounding context too, so all types have to be fully qualified or imported.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.util.Try

def unsafeCompile[A](code: String): A = {
  val tb = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  tb.compile(tb.parse(code))().asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

The above function throws exceptions and does not really check if the cast to `A` is a valid one, so you can get `ClassCastException`s in unknown places if not used correctly.

But now, getting instances at runtime is just a matter of a few LOCs:

```
enumerateBOs.map { obj =>
  Try {
    val f = unsafeCompile[Any => Unit](s"""
      import your.package_.with_.Printer
      // any additional imports for instances go there too

      implicitly[Printer[_root_.${obj.getClass.getCanonicalName}]].print _
    """)
    f(obj)
  }
}
```

I'm assuming you're not using anonymous classes - their `getCanonicalName` returns `null` and you'll need some fallback in that case. It's rather slow too.

Comment: That was an awesome answer. Both answering the actual question and providing a different solution. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone looking at this later on: To get my real life example to work, I had to switch from .compile to using .eval and put the line `implicitly[Printer[_root_.${obj.getClass.getCanonicalName}]].print _` into curly braces.